# "change you want to make in the world"

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

I'm pretty sure one should say "make changes", instead of "do changes". But is such a phrase grammatical?

> "Focus on the *change you want to make in the world*"

I think the most idiomatic way of saying this would be "focus on what change you want to bring about in the world". But is the above quote correct? Is it idiomatic to say "change(s) someone *makes in the world*"?

When I googled "change you want to make in the world" I got few results, most could be comments from non-native speakers (the [Google results](https://google.com/search?q=%22change%20you%20want%20to%20make%20in%20the%20world%22) shows 590000 results on the first page, but if you try to reach page 9 you'll see there are only about 75 cases)

Comment: What makes you think a construction like [*the changes he made*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+changes+he+made&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) might *not* be "valid"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers good point, I think it just sounds weird to me. When I googled "change you want to make in the world" I got few results, most could be comments from non-native speakers (the Google results shows 590000 results on the first page, but if you try to reach page 9 you'll see there are only about 75 cases) https://www.google.com/search?q=%22change+you+want+to+make+in+the+world%22

Comment: Do you think it sounds more natural with the implied *that* present? - "Focus on the change *that* you want to make in the world"

Comment: If you want to ask whether something is wrong, you should provide a reason for why you think that it might be wrong. Otherwise it's just a proofreading request, which is off-topic. (Edit: I see that FF raised the same issue. "Sounding weird" is rarely a good reason. The Google research may be a good reason, but it should go in the question, not in a comment.)

Comment: Changes are always being made. Changes ***you want*** to make will be less common, and changes you want to make ***in the world*** will be even less common. But they're all just ordinary English.

Comment: Thanks! I see your point @MarcInManhattan , I can't fully explain why I thought it was weird, I think it relates to FumbleFingers last comment, that it's uncommon. But the implied "that" made it sound a lot better to my non-native ears. Thank you for clarifying it's idiomatic still

Comment: What is the intended meaning of "**in** the world"?  Where else could one make them?

Comment: @RayButterworth the idea was to single out some improvement in the world (on, say, social, environmental or economic issues, i.e. in regard to "world problems") that the interlocutor would like to promote -- thus, it's kind of broad (it could be a local or global change)

Comment: @flen, in that case, I think I'd have said "*to* the world".